# How to begin creating a web application using a Python and xlrd/django script?

Tags: django, python-2.7, xlrd

I'm not sure where to begin, as in do I start working towards PHP, Ruby or what, but here is what I'd like to do:

I have a Python script that takes a pre-formatted Excel document and using xlrd and Django, I output a nicely formatted HTML page, based on a template HTML page.

But currently on my team, I'm the only one that can use this Python script because our setups, and I'd like to simplify the process by creating a web app that has a couple drop down menus to specify which script to run, then let me upload the .xls file, at which point the HTML file is automatically generated and a download link is created or the HTML file is spit out somehow.

Does anyone have any guidance as to how I should even begin this project?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a good read of the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/), and probably working through the [tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

Django's documentation is very good.

If you just want to hack at the code you've got then probably read the following to get a very basic overview of some core django functionality -

- [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/)
- [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/)
- [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/)
- [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/)
- [templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/)

With your app, the url dispatcher will pass the request to a view which will use a template to render your excel document.

You want a form to handle your user parameters and a single view to render and process the form and also render the excel template.